# reactively add resources and events to fullcalendar

Tags: meteor, fullcalendar

my current take on displaying reactive resources and events is not optimized , since i have put the whole fullCalendar init block inside a deps.autorun , which works , but each time a new event is added the calendar always comes back to the current week , which is normal since it is re instantiated on each reactive variable change inside the deps.autorun.
is there any better solution to add reactive events and resources ?
here's a code snipet .
PS: i'm using this [lib](https://github.com/seankenny/fullcalendar/tree/v2)

```
Deps.autorun(function() {
    // Initialize the external events


    $("#calendar").fullCalendar("destroy");

    calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title'
        },
        disableDragging: true,
        defaultView: 'resourceWeek',
        firstDay: 1,
        editable: true,
        selectable: true,
        displayEventTime:false,
        minTime: 8,
        snapMinutes:10,
        weekNumbers: false,
        weekNumberTitle: 'Viikko ',
        refetchResources: true,
        maxTime:16,
        selectHelper: false,
        eventRender: function (event, element) {
            var originalClass = element[0].className;
            element[0].className = originalClass + ' hasmenu';
            $(element[0]).attr('shift-id', event._id);
            element.find('.fc-event-title').html(event.title);
            element.bind('mousedown', function (e) {
                if (e.which == 3) {
                    Session.set("selectedShift",event._id);
                }
            });

        }, dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view,res) {

            Session.set("selectedDay",date);
            Session.set("selectedRessource",res.id);

        },
        eventAfterRender: function(event, element, view) {
            $(element).css('width','80px');
        },
        resources: function(){
            var data;
            data = Meteor.users.find({$and: [{roles: {"$in": ['employee']}},{status:"staffed"}]});
            return data.map(function(c) {

                img =Images.findOne({_id: c.picture});
                imgUrl="";
                if (!c.name) {
                    c.name = "";
                }
                if(!img){
                    imgUrl="/images/default-avatar.png"
                }else{
                    imgUrl = img.url();
                }
                return {
                    id: c._id,
                    //name: '<img alt="image" class="img-circle" src="'+imgUrl+'">' +c.profile.firstname +" " + c.profile.lastname
                    name: "<div class='img-profil small' style='background: url("+imgUrl+");'></div>" + c.profile.firstname + " " + c.profile.lastname
                };
            });
        },
        timeFormat: '',
        droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar
        drop: function (date, allDay, ev, ui, res) {

            // retrieve the dropped element's stored Event Object
            var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');
            var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);

            // assign it the date that was reported
            copiedEventObject.start = date;
            copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;
            calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                {
                    title: copiedEventObject.title,
                    start: date,
                    end: date,
                    allDay: false,
                    resource: res.id
                },
                true // make the event "stick"
            );
            shift =ShiftTypes.findOne({_id:copiedEventObject.id});
            startDate = moment(date);
            hour = shift.dayDuration.Start.split(":");
            startDate.hour(hour[0]).minutes(hour[1]);
            endDate = moment(date);
            hour = shift.dayDuration.End.split(":");
            endDate.hour(hour[0]).minutes(hour[1]);
            Schedules.insert({shiftId:shift._id,name:shift.name,uid:res.id,companyId:Session.get("companyId"),day:date,start:startDate.toDate(),end:endDate.toDate(),type:"active"})



        },
        select: function(start, end, allDay, jsEvent, view, resource) {
            // this is triggered when the day is selected, just like eventselect
        },
        resourceRender: function(resource, element, view) {
            // this is triggered when the resource is rendered, just like eventRender
        },
        eventDrop: function( event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, allDay, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view ) {
            alert('event moved to '+event.start+' to '+event.resource);
        },
        eventResize: function( event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view ) {
            endDate = moment(new Date(event.start));
            schedule = Schedules.findOne({_id:event.id});
            for(i=1;i<dayDelta+1;i++){
                Schedules.insert({start:moment(event.start).add(i,"days").toDate(),end:moment(schedule.end).add(i,"days").toDate(),uid:schedule.uid,companyId:schedule.companyId,name:schedule.name,shiftId:schedule.shiftId,attendanceCode:schedule.attendanceCode,type:"active"});
            }


        },
        eventClick: function ( event, jsEvent, view )  {
            toastr.success(moment(event.start).format('LT') +" TO "+moment(event.end).format('LT'))

        }
    });

    var data;
    data = Schedules.find({companyId:Session.get("companyId"),type:{$in:["active","activeAttendance"]}});

    // adding shifts to the calendar reactively inside the deps.autoRun

    data.forEach(function (row) {
        attendance = null;
        color="";
        if(row.attendanceCode){
            attendance =AttendanceCodes.findOne({_id:row.attendanceCode})
            color=attendance.color;
        }
        console.log(row.name);
        calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
            {
                title: row.name,
                start: new Date(row.start),
                end:  new Date(row.end),
                allDay: false,
                resource: row.uid,
                id:row._id,
                backgroundColor:color
            },
            true // make the event "stick"
        );
    });

});  // end Deps AutoRun , this Area should be improved
```

Comment: Not an expert on this specific lib, but couldn't you just call [`calendar.refetchResources()`](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/resource_data/refetchResources/) instead of deleting and recreating your calendar?

Comment: i will try this one , thanks